# Add all comma separated values in each cell together in column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[example of cells](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w51m5.png)I'm currently trying to add one specific column together  as each cell in the column has multiple values (1, 1, 4, 6),  These values need to be added together and replace the previous cells that has separated values.  using the formula LEN(Trim) works for one cell when pasting it directly into the google sheet but when adding it to a function in google script it returns the entire sheet in error as #Value even though the scope is C2:C. Any thoughts on what is happening?

```
    function sumAll() {
      //getValues of entire range and have it be  only column C 
    // create a foreach loop that will setFormula and iterate through each cell in the column ranging from C2 to the end of C 
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var columns = sheet.getRange("C2:C");
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = rows.getValues();
 
const len =  rows.setFormula('=LEN(TRIM(C2:C))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(C2:C),",",""))+1');
  for(var i= 0; i<columns.length; i++) {
        rows.setValues(len);


  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand perhaps an image could help

Comment: I added an image. column C is what is holding all the numbers I need to add together, column D is irrelevant.  I know the forEach loop is wrong in the code, and getDataRange is currently trying to add the formula to all Cells in the sheet. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function sumAll() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let o = vs.map((r,i) => [r[2].toString().split(",").reduce((a,c,i) => (a+=Number(c),a),0)]);
  sh.getRange(2,3,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Sheet0 (before):

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1,2,3,4 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 1,2,3,4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 1,2,3,4 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 1,2,3,4 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 1,2,3,4 | 8 | 9 |

Sheet0 (after):

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 10 | 4 | 5 |
| 2 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 10 | 6 | 7 |
| 4 | 5 | 10 | 7 | 8 |
| 5 | 6 | 10 | 8 | 9 |

Comment: Wow! Cooper you are a genius! this works perfectly. I am still learning the nomenclature of googles API/Sheets and really appreciate the assist!